# mandrill handlebars each loop - how to check odd items

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill

I'm using mandrillapp to send massive-customized email using send-api.
My template is using handlebar syntax recently supported by mandrill: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537 and the #each loop I'm using seems to work well.

Now I need to iterate little bit better: i.e. looking if the item in the each loop is odd or even, if is the last or something like that.

```
<div class="entry">
  {{#each products}}
    <div class="odd"> <!-- how to change class to even?-->
      <div>{{name}}</div>
      <div>{{price}}€</div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Note: I'm not talking about "handlebarsjs"  but only about the handlebar syntax available in mandrill templates

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't check that with something 
`{{#like @index % 2}}`
But if you have a list with properties, you can add the property "odd" to your list to check, so your list will look something like this:

```
products: [
    {'name': 'productName1', 'price': 22, 'odd': true},
    {'name': 'productName1', 'price': 22, 'odd': false},
    {'name': 'productName2', 'price': 13, 'odd': true},
    {'name': 'productName3', 'price': 42, 'odd': false},
    {'name': 'productName4', 'price': 63, 'odd': true},
]
```

And your mandrill template should look something like:

```
<div class="entry">
  {{#each products}}
    <div class="{{#if odd}}odd{{else}}even{{/if}}"> <!-- how to change class to even-->
      <div>{{name}}</div>
      <div>{{price}}€</div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: I always get the `else` conditional added to the class not the `odd` conditional. Even though the `ul` has many `li`s

Comment: @StevenAguilar check that your list has the 'odd' property set. This solution needs to have this property on the list before processing it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Handlebar.helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_even', function(conditional, options) {
 if((conditional % 2) == 0) {
  return options.fn(this);
 } else {
  return options.inverse(this);
 } 
});
```

and after you can use it in each loop, like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
    <li>{{ title }} {{#if_even}} even {{ else }} odd {{/if_even}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Mandrill does not allow registering custom handlebars helpers.